# How do I populate custom properties of a partial entity in Entity framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

say, I have a partial class that contains a custom property like this

```
public partial class Person {
    public string ImagePath{get;set;}
}
```

and I'm using `ExecuteStoreQuery<Person>` to pull out data, where a stored procedure is executed that joins *Person* and *Image* by `Person.ImageId = Image.ImageId` and gets the *ImagePath* field from *Image* table.

This doesn't seem to work for partial class, but perfectly for inheritance.

However, I don't want to use inheritant class in this case, so...is it possible for EF to be aware of the partial class's properties and populate them when executestorequery is executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If the `Person` class is mapped entity EF uses your mapping in EDMX file and it will populate only mapped properties because none of your custom properties from partial class is part of your mapping.

As a workaround create a new class `PersonView` which will not be mapped. Add all properties with the same name as columns in you result set and use it in `ExecuteStoreQuery`. In this case EF doesn't have mapping for the new class in EDMX so it will infer the simplest mapping - it will pair columns and properties by name.

Comment: I used inheritance as well! Thanks Walter! I think this really sucks about EF but you provided a great work around!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is kinda old but I bump to this problem just now and found a workaround, please see below method:

```
public IList<Person> GetPerson()
{
    var mod = (from p in Person
              join i in Image on p.ImageId equals i.ImageId
              select new 
              {
                  p.Name,
                  i.ImageId,
                  i.ImagePath
              }).ToList();

     return (from m in mod
            select new Person
            {
                Name = m.Name,
                ImageId = m.ImageId,
                ImagePath = m.ImagePath
            }).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class PersonList: Person
{
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
}

List<PersonList> myList = (
    from p in db.Person
    join i in db.Images on p.ref_image equals i.id
    select new PersonList()
    {
        id = p.id, name = p.name, ImagePath = i.path
    }
).ToList<PersonList>();

Console.Write(myList[0].id.ToString() + ", " +
    myList[0].name + " (" + myList[0].ImagePath + ")");
```