# Calculated column entity framework using raw sql and map to property

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I'm using EF 6 Database First.

In my database i have

```
Art             Tag              ArtTag
------          ----------       ----------    
Id              Id               ArtId  
Label           Label            TagId
```

In my .edmx file

```
 public partial class Tag
 {
    public Tag()
    {
        this.Arts = new HashSet<Art>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Art> Arts { get; set; }
}
```

And I added a partial class :

```
public partial class Tag
{
    public int ArtCount { get;set; }
}
```

I have 2 questions :

1. What is the best and efficient way to get using Linq all tags with ArtCount (total art count) property filled  ?
2. For question number 1, I tried using Raw Sql to get all tags with art count

   ```
   var tags = MyDataContext.Database.SqlQuery<Tag>(@"SELECT Tag.* , ArtCount FROM Tag 
               INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(ArtId) AS ArtCount, TagId 
               FROM dbo.ArtTag GROUP BY TagId) t ON t.TagId = Id 
               ORDER BY ArtCount DESC")
   ```

Somehow the ArtCount was never mapped to the EF ArtCount property in Tag object, i already tried decorating my partial class using  `[NotMapped]` or `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]` but it's always zero.

Do i miss something here ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865782/how-do-i-populate-custom-properties-of-a-partial-entity-in-entity-framework) help?

Comment: Thank you Andrei, yes it helped for my question number 2, well, i finally use inheritance like the thread suggested

Comment: As for the question 1. - `ICollection` actually has `Count` property. Unless I am missing something you can just use it (or call it inside `ArtCount` if you wish).

Comment: You are correct, i can definitely use the get { return Arts.Count() }, but since i disable LazyLoading, i thought i can use linq to get count without returning all Arts properties.

Comment: You could use .Include() to load related Art entities and then you should be able to do Arts.Count() even if you have lazy loading disabled.

Comment: I know that i could Include, but i would like to avoid getting all the Art, since i need only the count.